# MySQL processes stuck

Tags: mysql, sql, centos, percona

So, this is currently happening to me on live production sites:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH4aY.jpg

They worked fine for almost a month, and now they need to respond like 30+ seconds. Anyone know how to see queries of those processes or is it safe to kill them all?

Comment: You'll need to explain the problem in the ticket if you need help and upload images. The link could expire, and no one really wants to click on random links.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `top` or similar to look at MySQL. You need to actually log in to MySQL and use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see the queries being ran. You'll be able to see how long each query is taking and possible state of each query. You can then kill queries from within MySQL by using `KILL <id>`. Use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to see the entire query. Copy any long running queries and run `EXPLAIN` on them to see how many rows are being examined and if any indexes are being used.